# How do I set a Xamarin.Forms custom slider to update on tap on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using the MaterialSlider from [this](https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/MaterialDesignControlsPlugin/blob/develop/MaterialSliderControl.md) nuget package. I am aware of the `slider.On<iOS>().SetUpdateOnTap(true);` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/slider-thumb), but the MaterialSlider is a custom control with a private CustomSlider (inherits from Slider) within the class, so using `.SetUpdateOnTap(true)` directly on the MaterialSlider does nothing.

So my question is, how can I override the MaterialSlider to allow updating the value via taps and not just by dragging the thumb? I'm not too familiar with custom controls yet, so I don't really know where to start. Thanks.